# How to: Sequential db.batch with pg-promise

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I cannot figure out how to execute a batch call of generated queries sequentially.

I am trying to truncate every table in the DB. My code:

```js
db.any(`
  SELECT table_name
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_schema='public'
  AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
`)
.then(res => res.map(item => item.table_name)) // To get only an array with the names
.then(tables => tables.map(tableName => db.none(`TRUNCATE TABLE ${tableName} CASCADE`))) // ES6 template strings, because the table name must be bare here (no quotes)
.then(queries => db.tx(t => t.batch(queries)))
```

I get *deadlock detected* errors. It's clear why I am getting deadlocks: The queries cascade and try to truncate the same table as another query. That's why I need to call the queries synchronously. I can't figure out the way to do it. I tried using `db.sequence()`, but I was getting the same errors. What is the proper way of sequential execution of generated queries with `pg-promise`? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax supported by `pg-promise` is very flexible. Below is just one such syntax, which is the easiest to use for your case, and the most modern one:

```
await db.tx(async t => {
    const tables = await t.map(`
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = $1
        AND table_type = $2
    `, ['public', 'BASE TABLE'], a => a.table_name);

    for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        await t.none('TRUNCATE TABLE $1:name CASCADE', tables[i]);
    }
});
```

> // ES6 template strings, because the table name must be bare here (no quotes)

that is wrong, names must be in double quotes, which we provide with [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) filter.

Also see from [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters):

> Never use the reserved ${} syntax inside ES6 template strings, as those have no knowledge of how to format values for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you Vitaly for the answer, the great package and the way you support the community around it!